# Performing multiple operations atomically on a System.Collections.Concurrent object?

Tags: c#, multithreading

If I am using a collection from the `System.Collection.Concurrent` namespace, such as `ConcurrentDictionary<K, V>`, and I would like to keep another threads access and modification of this object from interleaving with my access and modifications.

**How would I do this?** If it is possible, wouldn't it end up being very slow when contending threads try to access the `ConcurrentDictionary` when these operations are taking place?

```
ConcurrentDictionary<KType, VType> conDict = ...;

// How do I ensure that these operation are performed atomically?
VType myVInst;
conDict.TryRemove(2, out myVInst);
conDict.AddOrUpdate(1, new VType(), (x, y) => y);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those data structures provide no means of allowing you to perform multiple operations on them in a conceptually atomic block.

If you are unable to write working code that only ever relies on a single method call being atomic, then you'll need to write your own concurrent data structure that specifically supports the operations you require or to use a non-concurrent data structure and synchronize all access to it.